# Исключить поле при сериализации или десериализации в Gson

Tags: java, gson

У меня в обьекте есть поле:

```
@SerializedName("CommentPhotoes")
@Expose(serialize = false)
private ArrayList<CommentPhoto> commentPhotos;
```

Мне это поле нужно распарсить когда я считываю этот объект из строки, но когда я его обратно сериализую в строку, это поле не должно туда попасть.

Проблема заключается в том что при сериализации объекта - это поле тоже сериализуется. При чем тоже самое касается и десериализации.

В чем может быть проблема, может я неправильно использую эти аннотации?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802887/5812238

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По умолчанию наличие аннотации [`@Expose`](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) ни на что не влияет. Поэтому при создании объекта [`Gson`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) с помощью [`GsonBuilder`](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) нужно явно указать, как обрабатывать эти аннотации.

Возможны варианты:

1. Помечать **нужные** поля этой аннотацией
2. Помечать **игнорируемые** поля этой аннотацией
3. Использовать модификатор `transient` вместо аннотаций

Подробнее:

1. **Помечаем поля, которые хотим сериализовать/десериализовать** аннотацией `@Expose`, при создании `Gson` объекта говорим, что поля без этой аннотации надо игнорировать:

   ```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
       .create();
   ```
2. **Помечаем поля, которые хотим игнорировать и в сериализации и в десериализации** аннотацией `@Expose`, при создании `Gson` объекта добавляем `ExclusionStrategies`:

   ```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
               return f.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> c) {
               return false;
           }
       })
       .create();
   ```

   Чтобы исключить поля **только в сериализации или только в десериализации** нужно добавлять аннотацию `@Expose` с параметром `serialize=false` или `deserialize=false`:

   ```
   class Book {
       // игнорируется только при сериализации
       @Expose(serialize = false) String field1;
       // игнорируется только при десериализации
       @Expose(deserialize = false) String field2;
   }
   ```

   и при создании `Gson` объекта настроить правильное исключение полей с этими аннотациями:

   ```
   new GsonBuilder()
       .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
               Expose expose = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
               return expose != null && !expose.serialize();
           }

           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> c) {
               return false;
           }
       })
       .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
               Expose expose = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
               return expose != null && !expose.deserialize();
           }

           @Override
           public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> c) {
               return false;
           }
       })
       .create();
   ```
3. Также чтобы исключить поле можно добавить к нему модификатор `transient`:

   ```
   class Book {
       transient String name;
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вы не настроили экземпляр `Gson`. Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17733569/3212712):

```
new GsonBuilder()
    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
            final Expose expose = fieldAttributes.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            return expose != null && !expose.serialize();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
            final Expose expose = fieldAttributes.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
            return expose != null && !expose.deserialize();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .create();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, рабочий код, но вынужден принять ответ diraria)

Comment: @KirillStoianov, да не вопрос) Другой ответ намного лучше)